# Receive multiple response from client error using TCP in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

So I was trying to make a code where TCP will accept all client which involves the repeat accept client but when I use that, I cant receive any response from the client so how do I solve this?

**The messagebox won't even pop up on the server**

code for the buffer location (Background worker):

```
while (true)
{
            try
            {
                client = network.AcceptTcpClient();
                streamer = client.GetStream();
                buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Client Connection Error");
                client.Close();
                streamer.Close();
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Code where ill show messagebox when client send a response back to the server (Background worker):

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (true)
        {
            string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, 
streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize));
            if (data == "Response_Command_329873123709123")
            {
                int slowdown = streamer.Read(buffer, 0, 
client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 
0,slowdown);
                worker.ReportProgress(0, message);
            }
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
 ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.UserState, "Client Response");
    }
```

Here is part of the code where client receives a response from server then send a server a message (Part of the code but mainly focus on this):

```
else if (data == "Messagebox_Command_2837190092703817203")
            {
                int txtbox = streamer.Read(buffer, 0, 
client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string txt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, txtbox);
                MessageBox.Show(txt, "Message From Server");
                byte[] database = 
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Response_Command_329873123709123");
                streamer.Write(database,0,database.Length);
                byte[] databases = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test");
                streamer.Write(databases, 0, databases.Length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my buffer part error but i fixed it

```
int databases = streamer.Read(buffers, 0, buffers.Length);
                string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffers, 0, databases);
                if (data == "Response_Command_329873123709123")
                {
                    byte[] datacen = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int main = streamer.Read(datacen, 0, datacen.Length);
                    var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(datacen, 0, main);
                    MessageBox.Show(message, "Client Response");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the UI from a non-UI thread (in this case a background worker).

Change:

```
while(true)
        {
            string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, 
streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize));
            if(data == "Response_Command_329873123709123")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, 
streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)), "Client Response");
            }
        }
```

...to:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    while(true)
    {
        string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                       streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize));
        if(data == "Response_Command_329873123709123")
        {
            var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                                   streamer.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize));

            worker.ReportProgress (0,  message);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.UserState, "Client Response");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but for some reason, this did not work

Comment: I have edit my question with the new code that you supplied me. So is there any error in the code? Tho i also did enable reportprocess

Comment: @zhiyan114 well naturally you need to apply the pattern above to your other workers.  Sorry I should have made that clear.  See how you go

Comment: Just quick one update on your answer, i actually got it fixed and yes, messagebox actually does show when it use in background worker.

Comment: @zhiyan114 post your claim as an answer for all to see